# Finding longest consecutive duration of an episode in multiple rows

Tags: r

What I have

```
ID | t | event
A | 1 | 0
A | 2 | 1
A | 3 | 1
A | 4 | 0
A | 5 | 1
A | 6 | 1
A | 7 | 1
A | 8 | 1
A | 9 | 0
B | 1 | 1
B | 2 | 1
B | 3 | 1
B | 4 | 0
B | 5 | 1
B | 6 | 0
B | 7 | 1
B | 8 | 1
B | 9 | 0
```

What I want

```
ID | maximum duration of event
A | 4
B | 3
```

A is 4 because the longest event duration was from t5 till t8.
B is 3 because the longest event duration was from t1 till t3.

I was thinking about numbering consecutive events in a new variable, restarting at 0 when there is a new ID, and then selection the maximum of that new variable grouped by ID. But  I couldn't figure out a way to do that. Any maybe it's not even the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The faster and easier to read version of Ananda's answer is:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(mydf) # convert to data.table in place

mydf[, max(rle(event)$lengths), by = ID]
#   ID V1
#1: A   4
#2: B   3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tapply` and `rle`:

```
tapply(mydf$event, mydf$ID, rle)
# $`A `
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:5] 1 2 1 4 1
#   values : int [1:5] 0 1 0 1 0
#
# $`B `
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:6] 3 1 1 1 2 1
#   values : int [1:6] 1 0 1 0 1 0

lapply(tapply(mydf$event, mydf$ID, rle), function(x) max(x$lengths))
# $`A `
# [1] 4
# 
# $`B `
# [1] 3
```

---

If you only want to consider runs of 1, then modify it as follows:

```
lapply(tapply(mydf$event, mydf$ID, rle), 
       function(x) max(x$lengths[as.logical(x$values)]))
```